# Using JQuery AJAX with non-unicode sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using JQuery '`.serialize`' + '`.post`' to send form data using ajax to a non-unicode, asp based website. The result data is url-encoded in unicode (characters are encoded in double values).

Can I post the form data encoded like it's sent using the form `submit()`, using JQuery ajax?

Comment: Try adding `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'` as a parameter of your post request. Not sure if that will work but worth a shot (as in: `$.ajax({
    url: '/your_asp_endpoint',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    type: 'POST'
});` )

Comment: thanks vibhu, this gives the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after hours and hours of trying...

Javascript uses UTF-8 for strings, and AJAX requests are always sent with UTF-8, period. There will always be a conversion on the server side if UTF-8 is not supported.

Description in the JQuery contentType parameter states:

> Data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset; you
>   must decode this appropriately on the server side.

So, eventhough there are QA's which claim some solutions as working, they are simply some conversions on the client & the server side. So firefox's firebug will always show UTF-8 characters on the net panel for AJAX requests, and it will never look like a submitted form with single byte characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 var encStr = encodeURIComponent(str)
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't try this right now as my platform has changed much since the question. I'll try to test it and return with the result. Maybe someone who can test it before me would share their result, so I can change the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't have time to set up the demo, but it resolved my long issue with submitting via ajax post non-unicode Chinese chars like gb2312 (for example http://tech.163.com/special/lanxizhuanlan/)